# How to get the second element alone from a list which contains 2 elements in c#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, list, element

This is my list definition

```
public class EventsList
    {
        public int EventID { get; set; }
        public string EventName { get; set; }
    }
```

This is C# code

```
string strCurrentUser = CommonWeb.GetLoginUser();
        EventsClass EventObj = new EventsClass();
        DataSet ds;
      List< EventsList> eventList = new List<EventsList>();
       EventsList eventobj = new EventsList();
       ds=EventObj.GetEvents(strCurrentUser);
```

I have a drop down in which it shoould display the EventName alone. How could i achieve this??

Comment: list[1] .......

Comment: Could you provide some code? What is your list? What is it's type?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, but it sounds like it might be as simple as using the [indexer of `List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc.aspx), which makes accessing an element look like array access:

```
List<string> values = ...;
string name = values[1]; // Index is 0-based
```

For a more general `IEnumerable<string>` you can use the [`ElementAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) extension method:

```
using System.Linq;

...
IEnumerable<string> values = ...;
string name = values.ElementAt(1);
```

Comment: and mention `values.ElementAtOrDefault(1)`

Comment: @it3xl: I think your comment does enough there... given that the question stipulates there are two elements in the list, I don't think it's needed in the answer.

Comment: Of course. `ElementAtOrDefault` is here for victims of search engines)

Answer (score 4):

```
.Select(i => i.Name);
```

e.g.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var records = GetPersonRecords();

            var onlyName = records.Select(i => i.Name);
        }

        private static List<Person> GetPersonRecords()
        {
            var listPerson = new List<Person>();

            listPerson.Add(new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Name1" });
            listPerson.Add(new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Name2" });

            return listPerson;
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: you are right but if the list is static you dont need this. a simple [1] is doing the same.

Comment: +1: taking into account the statement of the question, this is a good try

Answer (score 2):

it can be easily achieved using LINQ. Also, we can modify how we want to distinguish the required item.

```
var Item = oListItem.Select(x=>new Item()).Skip(1).Take(1);
```

**Skip** = How many items we want to skip
**Take** = How many we want to take

Answer (score 0):

Power of `Linq` we can achieve this...

Below example I Retrieve  the particular Property alone..

```
List<Item> oListItem = new List<Item>() {
    new Item("CD", "001CD", Enum.GroupTYPE.FAST_MOVING),
    new Item("TV", "002CD", Enum.GroupTYPE.FAST_MOVING),
    new Item("CD", "001CD", Enum.GroupTYPE.FAST_MOVING),
    new Item("LAPTOP", "003CD", Enum.GroupTYPE.FAST_MOVING),
    new Item("MOBILE", "004CD", Enum.GroupTYPE.NORMAL),
    new Item("CHARGER", "005CD", Enum.GroupTYPE.LEAST_MOVING)
};
```

*Retrieve  the Name property alone from the Collection*

```
var Item = from Item oname in oListItem select oname.ItemName;
```