# click one of many buttons with the same class name

Tags: c#

how can i click the second one of many buttons with the same class name in C#(webBrowser)..

```
<li class="uJiz5"><button class="g56EM  _7_FaD"> 1.Button <span class="MICM7 reportSpriteChevron"></span></button></li>
<li class="uJiz5"><button class="g56EM  _7_FaD"> 2.Button <span class="MICM7 reportSpriteChevron"></span></button></li>
<li class="uJiz5"><button class="g56EM  _7_FaD"> 3.Button <span class="MICM7 reportSpriteChevron"></span></button></li>
```

C# code(this clicks just first button):

```
foreach(HtmlElement btn in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
        {
            if (btn.GetAttribute("className") == "g56EM  _7_FaD")
            {
                btn.InvokeMember("Click");
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Get elements by class name (not tag name) and use the index `[1]` to get the 2nd one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the second element alone from a list which contains 2 elements in c#.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153562/how-to-get-the-second-element-alone-from-a-list-which-contains-2-elements-in-c)

Comment: @Archer Can you give an example, sir?

Comment: @Kokobey - use the debugger to see how many buttons are found and what the innerHTML of each is.

Comment: i can't do this, sir. I new in c#. It would be great if you could share a sample code block.

Comment: @Archer can you help me please?